# Get-SPSite vs Get-MgSite Powershell queries

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, site, microsoft-graph

What's the difference between the Get-SPSite vs Get-MgSite Powershell queries?

I read the documentation but am not able to see what's the difference between those.

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference between these commands is `Get-SPSite` uses SharePoint PowerShell and `Get-MgSite` uses Microsoft Graph Powershell

Also, as per the documentation [Get-MgSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.sites/get-mgsite?),

> Get-MgSite retrieves properties and relationships for a [site][] resource. A **site** resource represents a **team** site in SharePoint.